# How to get the MAX() value from a subtraction of two fields from the same row

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the table I'm working on

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM reacts;
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------+
| id  | userid             | messageid          | channelid          | upvotes | downvotes |
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------+
|   1 | 226790622768398336 | 621659327299715072 | 446794429597220868 |       1 |         1 |
|   3 | 226790622768398336 | 621662271642402817 | 446794429597220868 |       2 |         2 |
|   4 | 226790622768398336 | 621662782403903489 | 446794429597220868 |       2 |         1 |
|   5 | 226790622768398336 | 621663464527757313 | 446794429597220868 |       2 |         2 |
|   6 | 226790622768398336 | 621666397768122379 | 446794429597220868 |       3 |         2 |
|   7 | 276500077248512010 | 621669530996965383 | 446794429597220868 |       1 |         1 |
|   8 | 276500077248512010 | 621669605156323328 | 446794429597220868 |       1 |         1 |
|   9 | 276500077248512010 | 621669704653733889 | 446794429597220868 |       2 |         1 |
|  10 | 276500077248512010 | 621669842575032341 | 446794429597220868 |       2 |         1 |
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------+
```

And I want to `SELECT` the `MAX` value from the `SUM(upvotes - downvotes)`.

I've already tried to adapt the examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324280/mysql-select-and-calculate-value-from-multiple-columns) but with no success.

In a nutshell, I wanted to do a query that should be something like this (pseudocode):

```
SELECT id, 
       messageid, 
       channelid, 
       MAX(SUM(upvotes - downvotes))) AS total 
FROM reacts;
```

**EDIT**

For this data sample the output should be something like this:

```
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
| id  | userid             | messageid          | channelid          | total | 
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|   4 | 226790622768398336 | 621662782403903489 | 446794429597220868 |     1 |
|   6 | 226790622768398336 | 621666397768122379 | 446794429597220868 |     1 |
|   9 | 276500077248512010 | 621669704653733889 | 446794429597220868 |     1 |
|  10 | 276500077248512010 | 621669842575032341 | 446794429597220868 |     1 |
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Why isn't the row with `id = 4` or the row with `id = 9` or `id = 10` in the expected output ?

Comment: just updated the expected output. I didn't realize that there were other rows that return the same value.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(SUM(upvotes - downvotes))) AS total FROM reacts;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the particular user with the maximum sum, and you are using MySQL 8+, then window functions come in handy here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT userid, SUM(upvotes - downvotes) AS diff,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(upvotes - downvotes) DESC) rn
    FROM reacts
    GROUP BY userid
)

SELECT userid, diff
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you just want the single row from the entire table which has the maximum diff sum, then use a `LIMIT` query:

```
SELECT id, messageid, channelid, (upvotes - downvotes) AS diff
FROM reacts
ORDER BY diff DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If two or more records happened to be tied for the greatest difference in votes, and you want to see all ties, then we can use a subquery to find the max difference:

```
SELECT id, messageid, channelid, (upvotes - downvotes) AS diff
FROM reacts
WHERE (upvotes - downvotes) = (SELECT MAX(upvotes - downvotes) FROM reacts);
```

MySQL does not support any sort of with ties clause (which other databases such as SQL Server support), so we need a formal subquery.

Comment: "*MySQL does not support any sort of with ties clause*" - Disagree; especially when you answer does mention about the `Row_Number()` function. One can handle ties using [`Dense_Rank()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) function

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yes...but that requires an explicit subquery.